# Since the upwelling of calcium carbonate reduces surface pCO2, why is its dissolution in the CCD below the lysocline of concern?

Tags: climate-change, ocean-currents, carbon-cycle, ocean-models, carbonate

Why is so much of the literature I run across regarding global warming concerned with precipitating $\ce{CaCO3}$ to the ocean floor?

In areas of relatively lower pH, such as the eastern equatorial Pacific:

[Surface ocean pH and buffer capacity: past, present and future](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-55039-4)

[image]

Would not Ekman transport driven upwelling of $\ce{Ca+}$ ions that remain in solution (due to the extreme depth and cold of the ocean floor in that area) reduce the surface $\ce{pCO2}$, hence reduce $\ce{CO2}$ transport to the atmosphere?

[image]

Indeed, if anything, it seems geoengineering proposals to reduce atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ should be considering exposure of [eastern equatorial Pacific benthic carbonate platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonate_platform#Platforms_produced_by_the_%22tropical_factory%22) to dissolution in the [carbonate compensation depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonate_compensation_depth) (CCD) (i.e., below [the lysocline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysocline)).

[image]

Comment: What exactly is pCO2?

Comment: CO2 partial pressure.  e.g. if the partial pressure of atmospheric CO2 is less than the partial pressure of oceanic CO2, the ocean will outgas CO2 into the atmosphere.

Comment: Relevant: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19314/the-effect-of-co2-concentration-on-the-ph-of-the-ocean and the whole complex of ocean acidification and hypoxia.